# How to safely remove dried tire sealant from a carbon frame?

Tags: cleaning, tubeless, sealant

I have a carbon mountain bike frame with some good sections of tire sealant stuck on it (Stan's specifically).  If there an easy and/or safe method for cleaning unicorn juice off without hurting the frame?

Answer (score 2):

A credit card usually does the trick.

It's flexible enough to bend slightly but firm enough to serve as a scraper/pusher. It's soft enough that it won't scratch most finishes.